# Check for a pattern in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine the following list:

```
test_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22]
```

The list increases by 1 up to 5, then jumps to 20.
I want to write a piece of code that returns the number at which the list jumps for a particular sequence. In the above example, the answer would be 5.

The following piece of code does what I want; however, I am looking for a cleaner solution.

```
result = 0
for n, i in enumerate(test_list):
    if n+1 < len(test_list):
         if test_list[n]+1 == test_list[n+1]:
             result = test_list[n+1]
print(result)
```

Another example might be:

```
test_list2 = [1,3,5,7,9,20,21,22]
result = 0
for n, i in enumerate(test_list2):
    if n+1 < len(test_list2):
         if test_list2[n]+2 == test_list2[n+1]:
             result = test_list2[n+1]
print(result)
```

Comment: you can use numpy to find the index np.argmax(np.diff(test_list))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do sth along the following lines, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a grouping function that groups contiguos chunks:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22]

next(list(g)[-1][-1] for _, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1]-x[0]))
# 5
```

This of course does not work for the second case where the first chunk increments by 2. You would have to detect that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use numpy to find the index, and then access the list

```
idx = np.argmax(np.diff(test_list))
result = test_list[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers here but you could make your code in such a way that you don't have to hardcode your pattern.

Giving operation type and increment as arguments you could do something like:

```
test_list2 = [1,3,5,7,9,20,21,22]
result = 0
operation = "+"
increment = 2
for n, i in enumerate(test_list2):
    if n < len(test_list2) - 1:
         if eval(f'{test_list2[n]}{operation}{increment}') == test_list2[n+1]:
             result = test_list2[n+1]
print(result)
```

Actually it occurred to me that your code is returning the right value only when the pattern changes after the jump. If you want to be able to detect the jump even if the pattern remains the same afterwards, you have to break out of your loop:

```
test_list2 = [1,3,5,7,9,20,21,22]
result = 0
operation = "+"
increment = 2
i = 0
while i < len(test_list2) - 1:
    if eval(f'{test_list2[i]}{operation}{increment}') == test_list2[i+1]:
        result = test_list2[i+1]
    else:
        break
    i += 1
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
test_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22]
result = 0
for i in range(test_list[0],test_list[-1]):
    if i < test_list[i]:
        result = test_list[i-1]
        break
print(result)
```

this is my way to solve

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this if it should be done without any external libraries:

```
test_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22]
for i, v in enumerate(test_list):
    if i+1 < len(test_list) and test_list[i+1] != v+1:
        print(v)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be made simpler. One caveat is that your list must contain at least 3 elements otherwise the logic can't possibly work. This is because you use the first two elements to determine the interval (1 in your first example and 2 in your second). Thus the first comparison is based on that calculated interval and the difference between the second and third elements. If there is no break in the sequence, this function will return None.

```
test_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22]

def eos(L):
    assert len(L) > 2
    interval = L[1] - L[0]
    for i in range(2, len(L)):
        if L[i] - L[i - 1] != interval:
            return L[i - 1]


print(eos(test_list))
```